# What's the best wiki to run on Windows?

Tags: windows, sql-server, active-directory, wiki

I want to set up a wiki for my team.  I need it to run on Windows/IIS and if it needs a database, against SQL Server.

User-authentication must use/integrate with Active Directory, ideally natively rather than using LDAP.

Ideally, authorization would use Active Directory groups rather than something internal.

The ideal wiki would run on Server 2008 R2 x64, IIS 7.5 and SQL Server 2008 but these aren't requirements, just nice-to-haves.

Is there anything that fits these requirements and would you recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

This website should give you a definitive answer: http://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard.php

Comment: Thanks - I ran through it and it pointed me at ScrewTurn which several others have recommended.  +1 for it because it was qutie useful.

Answer (score 4):

We use [ScrewturnWiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) in our dev shop for the internal documentation.

It's a very mature open source implementation running as ASP.NET application. You can integrate user authentication with Active Directory and use SQL Server as backend database according to the information on the website.

Another candidate is Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server which offers Wiki-**like** features.

Comment: Emphatic negative on Sharepoint wiki - Its wiki ability is truly one of the most dreadful implementations I have ever witnessed.

Comment: +1 for Screwturn.  I have set it up for a number of different business's, and it has been well received each time.  Its a mature software package with an active developer base and community (that are very responsive if you have questions.

Comment: @Chris, if you are comparing the sharepoint Wiki to a standard WIKI, then yes it's crappy, however if you install the sharepoint wiki and use it like a regualr wiki you've missed the point.  THe sharepoint wiki is designed to allow the quick edits of a wiki page and combine the functionality of sharepoint and sharepoint search, screwturn isn't bad but then your stuck with  just wiki when your all done, with sharepoint if all yu want is a wiki then you can have it, but if other users want more it's there as well.

Answer (score 3):

I use Confluence from Atlassian (http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) which runs in an environment just like yours. Our teams found it really easy to start using and getting their content organised, even though most had never used a wiki before.

Comment: I've heard that Confluence is a delight to use but a bitch to administer.

Comment: @ptman - not necessarily. For example, you can draw users and groups from Active Directory, and the free adaptavist community bubbles plugin can help set up security templates, etc

Answer (score 2):

How many users?  Do you need any DMS or CMS functionality as well?

Sharepoint can be used as a Wiki though its real benefit is a Document Management System (DMS).  If you have a relatively small number of users it should suite your needs and fit in with your infrastructure.

Another popular .NET open source wiki project is DotNetNuke's Wiki Module.

Comment: A handful of editors with fewer than a hundred readers I think.  Not keen on SharePoint for this, although it does integrate nicely.  I did have a look at DNN ages ago and it seemed quiet complicated to set up.  Will give it another glance, though.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a simple & well designed wiki which is user friendly take a look at [Perspective Wiki](http://www.high-beyond.com/). It integrates easily with Active Directory.

Have also setup & used ScrewTurn wiki, which i can also recommend.

Answer (score 0):

MS SharePoint, you may use it's other features also e.g. Document library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but SharePoint's wiki didn't really feel like a proper wiki - it's not for me.